# Can not install shell-extensions from extensions.gnome.org

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm now using GNOME Shell 3.5.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 Desktop amd64

```
frederick@Frederick-Pasokon:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.5.4
```

When I visit the [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) site, it can normally display the `on` | `off` button. And if I slide the button to `on`, it will pop-up a window to ask me whether I want to install the extension or not.

And after I clicked `yes`, just nothing happened. If I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, the button resets to `off` as I've done nothing.

Trying installing some of the extensions will create a folder in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, but it's empty, without anything inside.

- I checked my unzip and it's up-to-date. - Please help me!

Comment: Are the extensions compatible with Gnome Shell 3.5.4?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've tried lots of them such as Remove Accessibility and so on, but none of them succeed